# Synchronization in Javafx

Tags: javafx, synchronization

I'm trying to make a method that returns after the user clicks on a rectangle in the stage. However, when calling wait() and then later notify() when the rectangle is clicked, the program freezes. How would one make a showAndWait() method in javafx?

I'm trying to make a class that asks a multiple choice question then returns the result, the below code is this class and it's commented where I attempted to put a wait and notify call.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
public class Question{
   int answer; //refers to the answer in the order of strings given
   // a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4

   String question;
   String a,b,c,d;

   public Question(String question, String a, String b, String c, String d, int answer){

      this.question = question;
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
      this.d = d;
      this.answer = answer;
   }

   private final double sideLength = 500;
   private volatile byte complete; //0 = no, 1 = true, -1 = false
   public synchronized boolean showAndWait(){
      complete = 0;
      Stage stage = new Stage();

      Pane pane = new Pane();
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

      stage.setScene(scene);

      stage.setResizable(false);
      stage.setMaxHeight(sideLength);
      stage.setMinHeight(sideLength);
      stage.setMaxWidth(sideLength);
      stage.setMinWidth(sideLength);



      double width = sideLength/3;
      double height = sideLength/5;

      double firstX = sideLength/9;
      double secondX = width + sideLength/9*2;

      double firstY = height + sideLength*2/5/3;
      double secondY = firstY * 2;


      Color base = Color.AQUAMARINE;
      Color wrong = Color.RED;
      Color right = Color.GREEN;



      Pane questionPane = makeAnswer(0,0,sideLength,sideLength/5, question, base, base);

      Pane ansA = makeAnswer(firstX, firstY, width, height,a,base, wrong);

      Pane ansB = makeAnswer(secondX, firstY, width, height,b,base, wrong);


      Pane ansC = makeAnswer(firstX, secondY, width, height,c,base, wrong);

      Pane ansD = makeAnswer(secondX, secondY, width, height,d,base, wrong);

      pane.getChildren().addAll(questionPane, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD);
      stage.show();

      //wait here, check to see if completed

      System.out.println(complete);
      return complete == 1;  
   }

   private double textShiftX = 30;
   private double textShiftY = 30;
   private int characterLimit = 20;
   private double textChangeY = 10;
   private synchronized Pane makeAnswer(double x, double y,double width, double height, String s, Color base, Color afterClick){

      Pane temp = new Pane();
      temp.setLayoutX(x);
      temp.setLayoutY(y);

      Rectangle rD = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
      rD.setFill(base);
      temp.getChildren().add(rD);

      for(int i=0;s.length() > 0;i++){
         String sTemp;
         if(s.length()>characterLimit){
            sTemp = s.substring(0,characterLimit);
            while(sTemp.charAt(sTemp.length()-1) != ' ')
               sTemp = sTemp.substring(0,sTemp.length()-1);
         }
         else
            sTemp = s;
         s = s.substring(sTemp.length());   

         Text t = new Text(textShiftX, textShiftY + textChangeY*i, sTemp);
         temp.getChildren().add(t);
      }



      rD.setOnMouseClicked( 
            (e)->{
               ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setFill(afterClick);
               complete = 1;

               //notify
            });
      return temp;
   }
```

Comment: Don't. You should not block the FX Application Thread. It's an event-driven toolkit, just register a listener and do whatever you need to do when the user clicks on the rectangle.

Comment: Can you just call [`stage.showAndWait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) instead of `stage.show()`?

Comment: Yes I can, thank you very much sir.

Comment: [The `Dialog` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) may also be worth a look since it's designed to return a result (e.g. in this case the answer chosen).

Answer (score 0):

```
Main class

public Scene createMainScene() {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        //root.setFillWidth(true);
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        TableView<Person> tblPeople = new TableView<>();
        tblPeople.setId("table");

        Button btnNew = new Button("New");
        btnNew.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        btnNew.setId("new");

        Button btnDelete = new Button("Delete");
        btnDelete.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        btnDelete.setId("delete");

        root.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("People"),
                tblPeople,
                btnNew,
                btnDelete
        );

        return new Scene(root);
    }

    public Stage createEditingStage(Stage owner) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setFillWidth(true);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        TextField txtFirstName = new TextField();
        txtFirstName.setId("firstName");
        TextField txtSurname = new TextField();
        txtSurname.setId("surname");
        TextField txtAge = new TextField();
        txtAge.setId("age");

        Button btnOK = new Button("OK");
        btnOK.setId("ok");
        btnOK.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        root.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("First Name"), txtFirstName,
                new Label("Surname"), txtSurname,
                new Label("Age"), txtAge,
                btnOK
        );

        // bit of a cheat, but really too simple to create a new controller
        btnOK.setOnAction(event -> stage.hide());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // set stage details
        stage.setTitle("New Person");

        // only has close button and cannot be resized
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        // rest of application cannot be interacted with until this stage is closed
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        // this stage belongs to another, i.e. will close if the owner does
        stage.initOwner(owner);

        return stage;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = createMainScene();
        Stage editingStage = createEditingStage(primaryStage);

        Controller controller = new Controller(scene, editingStage);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Example 4");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

public class Controller {
    private ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Controller(Scene scene, Stage editing) {
        setupPeople();
        linkToScene(scene, editing);
    }

    private void setupPeople() {
        people.addAll(
                new Person("Billy", "Bob", 17),
                new Person("Jane", "Doe", 20),
                new Person("John", "Doe", 19),
                new Person("Sammy", "Sue", 15)
        );
    }

    // Want to remember old position of pop-up window.
    private double oldX = 0, oldY = 0;

    private void linkToScene(Scene scene, Stage editing) {
        // region Set up TableView
        // Obtain reference to table view
        TableView<Person> tblPeople = (TableView<Person>) scene.lookup("#table");

        // Create columns and specify the properties they will be binding too
        TableColumn colSurname = new TableColumn("Surname");
        colSurname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("surname"));
        colSurname.setPrefWidth(100);

        TableColumn colFirstName = new TableColumn("First Name");
        colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        colFirstName.setPrefWidth(100);

        TableColumn colAge = new TableColumn("Age");
        colAge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("age"));
        colAge.setPrefWidth(100);

        // Add columns to table
        tblPeople.getColumns().addAll(
                colSurname,
                colFirstName,
                colAge
        );

        // Set data for table
        tblPeople.setItems(people);
        // endregion

        // add new person
        Button btnNew = (Button) scene.lookup("#new");
        btnNew.setOnAction(event -> {
            // Initialise
            TextField txtFirstName = (TextField) editing.getScene().lookup("#firstName");
            TextField txtSurname = (TextField) editing.getScene().lookup("#surname");
            TextField txtAge = (TextField) editing.getScene().lookup("#age");

            txtFirstName.textProperty().set("");
            txtSurname.textProperty().set("");
            txtAge.textProperty().setValue("0");

            // Restore old position if had one.
            if(oldX != 0) {
                editing.setX(oldX);
                editing.setY(oldY);
            }

            // Show and wait - waits for stage to close.
            editing.showAndWait();

            // Remember current position as the "new" old position.
            oldX = editing.getX();
            oldY = editing.getY();

            // Retrieve values
            Person person = new Person(
                    txtFirstName.textProperty().get(),
                    txtSurname.textProperty().get(),
                    Integer.parseInt(txtAge.textProperty().get())
            );

            // Add new person to list
            people.add(person);
        });

        Button btnDelete = (Button) scene.lookup("#delete");
        btnDelete.setOnAction(event -> {
            Person selected = tblPeople.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().getValue();
            if(selected != null) {
                people.remove(selected);
            }
        });
    }
}
```